# * in print statement of python

Tags: python, printing

I have this code to segregate odd and even numbers .
Can't understand why is there a star mark (*) when printing lists of odd and even in the last :

print(*even)
print(*odd)
what does the star imply , what happens if we don't use it

```
odd = []
even = []
# number of elemetns as input
n = int(input())
# elements as input
elements = list(map(int,input().split()))

#loop running across all elements
for element in elements:
    #if even, append to even[]
    if element%2 == 0:
        even.append(element)
    else:
        odd.append(element)

#print as a list delimited by space, without brackets
print(*even)
print(*odd)
```

#Code ends know it's a part of whole syntax of python print statement of using multiple objects , but still unclear .

Answer (score 0):

**As written in your own comment in the code:**

> *print as a list delimited by space, without brackets*

```
a = [1,2,3,4] 
print(*a)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4
```

**And,**

```
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**starred expressions have many benefits like**

```
print(*a,sep='\n')
```

**Can replace**

```
for i in a:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### (*) Operator used to unpack the numbers of arguments

```
without (*)operator print function
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(list1)
Output:
[1,2,3,4,5]

With (*) operator print function
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(*list1)
Output:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: This answer lacks any explanation of itself, look at the other answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The star gets rid of the normal list formatting.

```
#print(*even):
2 4 6

#print(even):
[2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

This allows you to print a list without having spaces or brackets, look at this link under "Unpacking a function using positional argument."

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-star-or-asterisk-operator/